# what is the significance of require attribute in anchor tag in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, anchor, href

While browsing through some tutorials I came across two implementations of `anchor` tag in `ReactJS`

1. `<a id="newtD" download={'Report'} href='./reports/product/myTest.xlsx' display = "none"></a>`
2. `<a id="newtD" download={'Report'} href={require('./reports/product/myTest.xlsx')} display = "none"></a>`

So, what is the significance of this `require` attribute inside `href` ?

Thanks.